# Garuda [Big Thiruvadi] and Hanuman [Small Thiruvadi]

Tags: vishnu, hanuman, garuda

Garuda the king of birds is the vahana of Sriman Narayana and his consort Goddess Lakshmi. He carries them on their shoulder and flies from one place to another. He will be on the skies hence known as Big Thiruvadi. Likewise Hanuman king of vanaras carry Lord Rama, Sita and Lakshmna on his shoulders from one place to other in land. Hence he is known as Small Thiruvadi.
Any mythological evidence for this? If so in which purana?

Comment: What is thiruvadi?

Comment: Can you make the question more clear with precise title? Btw, [this discussion](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/jan2001/0102.html) from ramanuja.org looks related

Comment: @Rickross Thiruvadi means the feet of  God.

Comment: @Pandya This is the shortest title I arrived after various thought process. Thiruvadi means feet of God.

Answer (score 1):

Garudazhwar is known as Periya Thiruvadi, since he is the Vahanam (vehicle) of Sriman Narayana and also all of his incarnations such as Krishna. But Hanuman is known as Siriya Thiruvadi since he is the vehicle/devotee of only one of the incarnations of Vishnu, namely Rama.

This practice of calling Garuda as Periya Thiruvadi and Hanuman as Siriya Thiruvadi is followed in the Srivaishnava tradition. Hence, there is no Puranic reference for this. Also, it is important to note that these terms are in Tamil, and Puranas are written in Sanskrit.

Comment: @ram Do not bring languages. In puranas there might be a instance of mentioning about the Thiruvadis be it in Sanskrit or French or Tulu. Answer is inappropriate coz Hinduism is a ocean. You have to explore.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan What I am saying is that they may be mentioned in Sanskrit, but not in Tamil..

Comment: Of course, Where is the citation from Sanskrit? Your  answer is my question.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan I am saying that there is no citation in Sanskrit..

Comment: @Ram Then put your answer in comment. If the answer is given then citation to be quoted.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan There is no citation as the terms Periya Thiruvadi and Siriya Thiruvadi are NOT mentioned in the Puranas.